# HDMI cable causes extreme video lag in Ubuntu?

Tags: video, hdmi, tv

I have a 42" Vizio TV hooked up to a Thinkpad E550 (running Ubuntu 14.04).

When I hook up these two devices with a VGA chord, everything is perfectly fine; **however, when I hook these two devices up with an HDMI cable, the video on the TV is extremely laggy (to the point of it not being usable).**

Why is this?

Comment: Sounds like you need some GPU drivers.

Answer (score 0):

adjust the resolution (lower) so the laptop and tv match. set the main display to the external monitor (TV), but leave the display setting window open on the laptop, so you can switch it back when you need to (the text is blurry and small on the tv). this worked for me, fixed all the choppy lag. :)